# Access phone over home wifi router using a fixed IP

Tags: http, networking, ip, wifi, router

I want have an app on my android phone (which I will write) which will respond to some HTTP request. The request is going to come from a programmable board/microchip (like Arduino) over the home wifi router. The programmable board would be able to send the request to a hardcoded URL.

(I don't understand networking. So, please pardon me if my next statements are technically ambiguous/incorrect.) I would NOT be running the HTTP server on my phone over a public/constant IP. My phone currently shows me a private IP of 192.168.1.4. I am guessing it might not remain the same every time as I and others in the house disconnect/reconnect various devices. Is there a way to ensure I reach my phone every time through some internal IP? I don't need it to be accessible from outside my wifi router.

Thanks.

-- Parag

Comment: Give your phone a static IP address, such as 192.168.1.100 or configure your router to give your phone the same IP address.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I didn't realize that I could configure my router to do that. I will try to figure that out. Thanks.